# Rails join from two table: how select attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, model, associations, rails-activerecord

In Rails 3.2.1

I have:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description
  has_many :subprojects
end


class SubProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id_name, :description, :num_alloc, :project_id
  belongs_to :projects
end
```

How can i return in a rails controller, an object that contain the "name" attribute (from the Project model) and the `id_name`, `description` and `num_alloc` (from the SubProject model).

In the controller, if i make

```
@results=  SubProject.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN.......)
```

`@results` contains only the attribute of the SubProject class because `SubProject.joins(...)` returns an `SubProject` object right?

So how can i return an object with attribute from the two model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start at your model definitions: Your `has_many` association needs to have an underscore in the name - `SubProject -> sub_project`:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name, :description
 has_many :sub_projects # !
end
```

Next, your `belongs_to` needs to be in a singular form:

```
class SubProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id_name, :description, :num_alloc, :project_id
  belongs_to :project # !
end
```

After you make these changes, you can query:

```
@sub_projects = SubProject.includes(:project).all
name = @sub_projects.first.project.name
...
```

Answer (score 7):

```
@subproject = SubProject.select("subprojects.id_name, subprojects.description, subprojects.num_alloc, projects.name").joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN projects ON projects.id = sub_projetcs.project_id")
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use only one object to avoid multiple SQL queries (what other reason ?), you can do that:

```
@results = SubProject.includes(:projects).where(...)
```

Then you can do

```
@results.first.projects.name
```

This won't trigger a new SQL query.

Moreover, if you add one line in your SubProject  definition

```
class SubProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :name, :to => :projects, :prefix => true
  ...
end
```

Then you can write:

```
@results = SubProject.includes(:projects).where(...)
@results.first.projects_name
```

So you have virtually *an object with attribute from the two models*, as you asked.