# How to get rails to do the correct single SQL join query for this iteration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have basically no experience with Rails, and I'm trying to help a friend who is learning how to program, but I have a lot of experience with SQL, and I'm struggling to get Rails to do the right thing for a simple query with a join.

I have a two tables, `drawings` and `drawing_types`.  `drawings` has a foreign key pointing into `drawing_types`, which has a `type_description` column.  This is obviously the most bare bones relation you can imagine.  In SQL, I'd do this to get all the drawings with their correct `type_descriptions`:

```
SELECT d.*, dt.type_description FROM drawings as d
INNER JOIN drawing_types as dt ON dt.id = d.drawing_type_id;
```

This is a single efficient SQL query that returns exactly what I want: a list of drawings that also have their text type description.

I cannot, for the life of me, get rails to generate and use a single query like this.  The best I can do is get it to do two queries, which clearly indicate it's doing the "join" in code, rather than letting the db do it.  Sometimes it likes to do N+1 queries!?!

Here is the code for the model:

```
class Drawing < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image, :drawing_type_id
  belongs_to :drawing_type
end

class DrawingType < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :type_description
  has_many :drawings
end
```

Here is the relevant controller code:

```
@drawings = Drawing.includes(:drawing_type)
```

And here is the view:

```
<% @drawings.each do |drawing| %>
  <tr>
    <td><b><%= drawing.drawing_type.type_description %></b></td>
```

This generates two SQL queries, one on `drawings.*`, and the other to get all the descriptions, which are then clearly being looked up in code.  If I change the `includes` to a `joins` it does 1+M+N SQL queries (M = number of drawing types, N = number of drawings)!?!?!?!

I can get it to emit the correct SQL join to the log by using this (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14357110/2119732)):

```
@drawings = Drawing.select("drawings.*, drawing_types.type_description").
     joins("INNER JOIN drawing_types ON drawing_types.id = drawings.drawing_type_id")
```

but, rails only seems to use the result as an array of drawings, ignoring the `type_description` column in the result, so it does an additional M+N queries!

All of these variations "work" in the sense that the page renders correctly for all of them, but they are all the wrong way of doing this simple thing, relative to the single correct SQL join that should be executed.

There simply has to be a simple way to do this correctly since it's the most basic of relations you might find in a totally boring website schema, but I have searched high and low, including reading lots of answers here and all the docs, and have not been able to figure out how to do this.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem recently in work, and found that you can do this using `.joins()` and `.select()`. I found the best way to prototype was to try different things in the rails console until you get the query that you want.

Controller:

```
@drawings = Drawing.joins(:drawing_type).select([:name, :description]).all
```

This will generate:

```
Drawing Load (0.4ms)  SELECT name, description FROM `drawings`
  INNER JOIN `drawing_types` ON `drawing_types`.`id` = `drawings`.`drawing_type_id`
```

In my example I have a field 'description' on DrawingType, rather than 'type_description', but this should be the only difference.

And the corresponding code in in the View:

```
<% @drawings.each do |drawing| %>
  <tr>
    <%= content_tag, :td, drawing.name %>
    <%= content_tag, :td, drawing.description %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ah, okay, this works as expected (ignoring that it's obfuscated and necessary in the first place), thanks!  One additional note for anybody from THE FUTURE reading this, I had to use a string in the `select` because I couldn't figure out how to disambiguate shared column names (like :id), so I did `.select(["drawings.*", :type_description])`.  Also, it's worth emphasizing that this solution puts the attributes directly on the returned object, so `drawing.type_description` is how you access it, where in normal `includes` syntax you'd use `drawing.drawing_type.type_description`

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is intentional, as in many cases using two queries will run quicker than one. See this answer for a good explanation of the reasoning: [How do I avoid multiple queries with :include in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246826/how-do-i-avoid-multiple-queries-with-include-in-rails)

That said, you can force a single query by specifying a *where* condition on the relation, but it's not recommended.

Comment: Thanks.  I find that quite surprising, since it appears to make non-scalable assumptions about how you're going to iterate the resulting rows, as you can see in that person's followup [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719607/how-to-eagerly-load-the-single-foreign-reference-efficiently-with-activerecords), and the where condition thing seems like a weird way to request the join, but I appreciate the answer and I'll test that out.

Comment: So, I tried this with a simple `where` using a column from the left table and it still did the two queries, but if I do the `where` with the right side joined table it generates a single SQL query that's pretty ugly, but at least is a single query.  But, the existence of the `where` doesn't force the query, only if you're doing a condition on the joined table, and then the query is filled with a bunch of machine generated AS names to hook it back up.  Marc's suggestion below generates the simpler query, plus it does the right thing with putting the joined attributes directly on the object.